# WordPress/WooCommerce: Adding PHP include with condition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on including certain elements based on product tag within the WooCommerce Product Template file.

So I have 1 `content-single-product.php` file, however I want to dynamically render a PHP file into the `content-single-product.php` file based on the tag assigned to the unique product.

So, the nature of the button is to place a "bid", however the company operates in 3 different locations and thus would like to display different forms dependent on where the product is (E.g. Oxford, Cheltenham, Swindon).

I've created the 3 different forms and uploaded them as unique PHP files, and attempted this but with no luck:

```
if(is_product_tag('Cheltenham')) {  include 'place_bid_cheltenham.php'; }
```

However even though I've set the product tag to "Cheltenham" it's still not rendering, when analysing the Div element containing this it's just empty, however the page loads fine with no syntax errors.

Also, when I remove the `IS_PRODUCT_TAG` condition, the button renders correctly.

Comment: why include try using [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for getting back to me, I tried this and now I get the following error: (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING).

Comment: what is the code you are using?

Comment: `<div class="place-bid-btn"><?php if(is_product_tag('Cheltenham')) { include 'place_bid_cheltenham.php'; }  ?></div>` When I remove the if condition Eg: `<div class="place-bid-btn"><?php include 'place_bid_cheltenham.php'; ?></div>` it works.

Comment: try using double quotes in include

Comment: @RohitKishore double quotes should be irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Guys, Tried all of above, not working correctly, have tried referencing the tag as the tag name and ID and no luck.

Comment: try turning on [wp debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to get error information.

Answer (score 0):

`is_product_tag()` is for determining if you are viewing the taxonomy page for that term. It is a wrapper for the `is_tax()` function like so...

```
function is_product_tag( $term = '' ) {
    return is_tax( 'product_tag', $term );
}
```

So it is not what you need in this case. Instead, you will want to use the `has_tag()` function, which is a wrapper for `has_term()`, to determine if the product has been tagged.

```
if( has_tag('Cheltenham') ) {  
    include 'place_bid_cheltenham.php';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've just attempted this however and now it doesn't work, does this function work in WooCommerce? as I can't seem to find it here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: `has_tag()` is part of WordPress ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/ ). Is this conditional check being done inside the loop?

Comment: This is literally the code I have added (wrapped in a div)  <div class="place-bid-btn"><?php if( has_tag('Cheltenham') ) {  include 'place_bid_cheltenham.php'; }  ?></div>